# public uri automatically appears in the url laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I am using shared hosting for hosting a laravel application.
I have used a .htaccess file to redirect request to the public folder

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php[L]
```

the laravel routing works perfectly but when i try to request a folder inside the public folder directly from the url a public uri automatically appears

eg:
when i write **"www.domain.com/Uploads"** the url automatically becomes **"www.domain.com/public/Uploads"**

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use htacess to access your files. A better way to do it is to build a route that fetches the file you need and present it to you.

Lets say the url is

```
project.dev/images/image.jpg
```

Building a route like this will fetch the file you need

```
Route::get('/images/{name}', function($name) {
    $file = Storage::get('images/'.$name);

    return response($file, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'Content-Type: image/png'
    ]);
});
```